# Understanding SQL Server Audit and the .sqlaudit logfile

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ddl-trigger

**Re: SQL Server AUDIT component of SQL Server 2008 EE or SQL Server 2012 EE**

1) Has anyone been able to produce a test harness (ie. T-SQL) that maps what DDL statements trigger what Audit Events? Eg. `DROP TABLE [table-name]` triggers the `DATABASE_CHANGE_GROUP` event.

Yes, this test harness would be quite large but very well worth putting together as a reference. I presently don't have the time to do this, and I can't see any easy/quick way of 'reverse-engineering' this info from the `.sqlaudit` logfile (although there must be a way as I can see a commercial product called 'LOGbinder SQL' doing something similar - see http://www.logbinder.com/products/LOGbinderSQL/default.aspx).

2) Has anyone worked out how to parse the `.sqlaudit` logfile with respect to my point 1 above? I suspect there must be a way of joining tables (`.sqlaudit` and others like `sys.dm_audit_class_type`), using `action_id` and `class_type` etc from `.sqlaudit`, to produce more specific information (ala LOGbinder).

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Log File Viewer.
2. Use Log File Viewer.

The only easy to do this is tracing (TRACEON).